# Count the number of custom posts per user

Tags: php

I am using JetEngine, and the users can create CCTs (custom content types), that have a single post CPT

I know already how to count the number of posts by the user, I am using shortcode for that

```
function total_user_post_shortcode() {
    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
    if ( 0 != $current_user->ID ) {
        echo $user_post_count = count_user_posts( $current_user->ID );
    }
}

add_shortcode('total-user-posts', 'total_user_post_shortcode');
```

But I want to specify just a certain type of custom post, not all of them.

How should I change the code?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use the second parameter `$post_type`:

```
count_user_posts( $current_user->ID, 'my_post_type' );
```

More information on [`count_user_posts()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/count_user_posts/)